# C++ Keeping Track of the Longest Streak

Tags: c++

For my computer programming class, I decided to make a program that generates a random coin flip and keeps track of the longest consecutive streak for both heads and tails. I have searched the internet and found no answer. The count is not displaying right. Even just a hint would be great!
Thanks,
Justin

```
int main(){

    int number_of_flips;
    int coin_flip;
    int previous_flip = 2;
    int head_count = 0;
    int tail_count = 0;
    int highest_head = 0;
    int highest_tail = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << "Enter the number of coin flips:" << endl;
    cin >> number_of_flips;
    system("cls");

    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_flips; i++){


        coin_flip = rand() % 2;

        if(coin_flip == 0){
            cout << "Heads" << endl;
            if(coin_flip == previous_flip){
                  head_count = head_count + 1;       
             }
             else{
                 if(head_count > highest_head){
                     highest_head = head_count;                  
                 }

                 head_count = 0;      
             }
        }

        if(coin_flip == 1){
            cout << "Tails" << endl;
            if(coin_flip == previous_flip){
                  tail_count = tail_count + 1;        
            }
            else{
                 if(tail_count > highest_tail){
                      highest_tail = tail_count;              
                 }

                 tail_count = 0;     
            }
        }


        previous_flip = coin_flip;
    }

    cout << "The longest run of heads is " << highest_head << endl;
    cout << "The longest run of tails is " << highest_tail << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
Tails
Tails
Tails
Heads
Heads
Tails
Tails
Tails
Tails
Heads
The longest run of heads is 1
The longest run of tails is 2
```

As a reference, here is my final code that I believe works now:

```
int main(){

    int number_of_flips;
    int coin_flip;
    int previous_flip = 2;
    int head_count = 0;
    int tail_count = 0;
    int highest_head = 0;
    int highest_tail = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << "Enter the number of coin flips:" << endl;
    cin >> number_of_flips;
    system("cls");

    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_flips; i++){


        coin_flip = rand() % 2;

        if(coin_flip == 0){
            cout << "Heads" << endl;
            if(coin_flip == previous_flip){
                  head_count = head_count + 1;       
             }
             else{
                 if(head_count > highest_head){
                     highest_head = head_count;                  
                 }

                 head_count = 1;      
             }
        }

        if(coin_flip == 1){
            cout << "Tails" << endl;
            if(coin_flip == previous_flip){
                  tail_count = tail_count + 1;        
            }
            else{
                 if(tail_count > highest_tail){
                      highest_tail = tail_count;              
                 }

                 tail_count = 1;     
            }
        }
        previous_flip = coin_flip;
    }
    if(head_count > highest_head){
           highest_head = head_count;              
    }
    if(tail_count > highest_tail){
           highest_tail = tail_count;              
    }
    cout << "The longest run of heads is " << highest_head << endl;
    cout << "The longest run of tails is " << highest_tail << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question ? What error do you get ?

Comment: The program doesn't calculate the streak right.

Comment: You are using `previous_flip` before assigning to it; it probably contains some random value (though reading it is technically UB)

Comment: Thanks Seth, I initialized it as two and it fixed the problem of the count being off by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't take into account the *last* streak, because you only check against `highest_head` or `highest_tail` when the *next* flip is different. On the last flip, there is no next flip.

Since this is homework, I'll refrain from suggesting how to fix your code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Greg and I understand not suggesting the exact code. I read what you suggested and still don't understand what exactly you are saying. I updated my original post with a sample output.

Comment: I would suggest printing out more of what is going on inside your program as it runs. For example, `cout << head_count << " " << highest_head << " " << tail_count << " " << highest_tail << endl;` on every loop iteration. The next tip is that you're only incrementing the count when you get *two* of the same flip in a row.

Comment: Thanks for the hints Greg! I believe I have gotten it to work. After implementing what you suggested into my loop, I noticed the highest count wasn't being stored if the highest count was the last count. I amended my post with what I believe is the fixed code.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Greg answer, if `previous_flip` is initialized to 0(it could because you're not doing it yourself explicitly, it could also be anything else, but usually in debug it is 0) and your first flip is 1, your count will be off by one as well.

There's a couple of mistake but I won't post code either.

First, you never count the first flip that is different than the last one. You're incrementing the flip count only if the current flip is equal to the last flip. Right there, you're missing one.

Then, you set your max streak only if the current flip is not equal to the last one. What then happens is you can only count the first streak correctly(assuming you count the first flip right) because the second streak will get its max streak updated only when it returns to the same flip. Here's what occuring with the sequence you provided:

```
Tails   // Does not count this one because flip != last_flip
Tails   // tail_count is 1
Tails   // tail_count is 2
Heads   // Does not count first flip on flip switch, reset head_count to 0
Heads   // head_count is 1
Tails   // Does not count first flip, set max_tail to 2, reset tail_count to 0
Tails   // tail_count is 1
Tails   // tail_count is 2
Tails   // tail_count is 3 but will never be set unless we flip head, then tail.
Heads   // Does not count first switch, set max_head to 1, reset head_count to 0
```

Now fix that algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the visuals Eric. I believe I have fixed my code. I added the code to the original post. Could you take a look?

Comment: It's not how I would do it but if you test it and it returns the right numbers, I guess it is alright.

Comment: It does return the numbers correctly. How do you suggest doing it? I will not use your suggested code for this assignment, I would just like to know how _you_ would solve this problem.

Comment: I would personally increment count and set max if needed at every flip of a kind and I would reset count on the other kind. So something like  this: increment this kind, set max if needed, reset other kind since this is a switch. You could then skip you check at the loop exit and wouldn't need to remember last flip.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. I appreciate the advice.

Comment: Consider upvoting and accepting an answer. This is what makes people come back to this site.